# How to parse xml file with schema in object c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can't find any library support parse xml file with schema in iphone sdk ? do you know any lib support this ?

Comment: Please Improve your question writing.....

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link mentioned below....

There is ASIHTTPRequest for parsing XML in iPhone

> [Link1](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest-goes-iPhone)
>
> [Link2](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)
>
> [Link3](http://www.building43.com/blogs/2010/05/28/reading-rss-feeds-on-iphoneipad-with-asihttprequest-and-cocoa-rss/)

and try yourself....

Answer (score 0):

Apple has added support for SAX xml parsing.You can use built in NSXMLParser for simple xml parsing.You will get detailed insight about the delegate methods in apple documentation.

There is one more parser which is widely used,called libxml2 parser.It supports both DOM and SAX parsing and is based on open source C-APIs.This library is included in iPhone SDK and you can add it in your project easily.This is currently used in Twitter oAuth integratin on iPhone.

There are other parsers as well, you can compare performance of different parsers [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project).